# can somebody explain this line of code:

Tags: cakephp

I did not understand this code, what is happening in this line ?

```
   $this->request->data['User']['restaurant_name'] = trim($_restaurants[$this->request->data['User']['restaurantid']]);
```

Comment: It seems `$_restaurants` is an array containing all restaurant name as value and id as key. So the above code is trying to get the name of restaurant from that array by the key provided.

Comment: Seriously? Start here http://php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php

Comment: @burzum what part of that (very simple) question is about OOP? user3792730 if you're trying to do something and having problems _please ask how to do that_.

Comment: @AD7six I simply mean he should read the php manual - from the very beginning. The question shows *zero* effort and a huge lack of php basics knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Seems in the `user` table having a field named `restaurant_name` .

in the right side `$this->request->data['User']['restaurantid']` holds the `id` of `restaurant` table and `$_restaurants` holds the all restaurants data,so basically you are assigning `restaurant_name` to the request data.